# Generate a list of numbers equal to the number of rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with 7 rows; I want a query which will return the values shown in the second query, using the using total number of rows in the table, without using the table name.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `graph_owner` (
  `owner_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`owner_id`)
 
);
INSERT INTO `graph_owner` (`owner_id`, `owner_name`) VALUES
(1, 'test1'),
(2, 'test2'),
(3, 'test3'),
(4, 'test4'),
(5, 'test5'),
(6, 'test6'),
(7, 'test6');


SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5
    UNION SELECT 6
    UNION SELECT 7
) AS t
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0ded/1)

Comment: SQLFiddle is good but put your table/data structure here.

Comment: why nagative?..if there is any problem please tell....dont do nagative directely

Comment: @Michael Berkowski....thanks for editing

Comment: You mean you want to generate a list of numbers from 1 to N where N is the number of rows in your table?

Comment: yes correct but without using any table name in query....just using count N only

Comment: How do you know the number of rows in the table without querying the table itself?

Comment: you can use it in to inner query is where you give condition....but outer query id without using table name

Answer (score 0):

```
select owner_id from graph_owner order by owner_1d
```

Comment: your answer is correct but can you tel me how to do it without using table name...only using count

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you don't really mean to do it without using the table name, as even you know that's impossible. Thus, I think you really mean that you don't want to select the contents of the column. You can number your rows:

```
select `graph_owner`.*,
(@rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1) rowNumber
from `graph_owner`, (select @rowNumber := 0) r
```

If you only want the number without the contents of the table:

```
select (@rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1) rowNumber
from `graph_owner`, (select @rowNumber := 0) r;
```

Here's an updated fiddle where I've changed the primary key to be not consecutive: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/703fe/4